# Change event not getting fired on model's 'set()' method with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, models

I am new to backbone.js. For my application, I need to call 'render' function when a change event in model occurs. Somehow it is not happening. Here is my code

```
function(data)
{
    alert(data);
    oTable.fnDestroy;
    servers.get(uid).on('change',this.render,this);
    servers.get(uid).set('serverStatus',status);
    servers.get(uid).off();
}
```

This is a very simple one but I am unable to to figure out why the event is not getting fired.

Comment: if you comment out the ```servers.get(uid).off();``` line, is there any change in the result?

Comment: What does `servers.get(uid)` return ?

Comment: Can you post more code which is relevant. Like the code for the view and the model.

Comment: Here is my model:
var Server=Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  idAttribute:'serverUUID',
  initialize:function()
  {
   console.log('server model created');
   this.on('change',function(){console.log('changed');});
  },
 });